# Why is an int required? Java Error: Found double, required int

Tags: java

I'm working on a code to read from a text file and display the maximum of the numbers. Using MaxArray[] the for statement is throwing an error because the input numbers are doubles and it is expecting an int. Any tips on what can be used to find the max of an array containing doubles?

```
  import java.io.*;

public class Read {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Rayman7337\\IdeaProjects\\Exam2\\src\\Data.txt"));

            String Num_1 = br.readLine();
            String Num_2 = br.readLine();
            String Num_3 = br.readLine();
            String Num_4 = br.readLine();
            String Num_5 = br.readLine();

            double Convert_1 = Double.parseDouble(Num_1);
            double Convert_2 = Double.parseDouble(Num_2);
            double Convert_3 = Double.parseDouble(Num_3);
            double Convert_4 = Double.parseDouble(Num_4);
            double Convert_5 = Double.parseDouble(Num_5);

            double MaxArray[] = {Convert_1, Convert_2, Convert_3, Convert_4, Convert_5};

            double Max = MaxArray[0];

            for(double i = 0; i<=4; i++){
                if (MaxArray[i] > Max) Max = MaxArray[i];
            }
            System.out.println("The maximum number is: " + Max);

        }catch (Exception ex){
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Array indices can only be `int`s. What would it mean to access the 2.5th element of an array?

Comment: This is evil code: `} catch (Exception ex) { return; }`.  It says "if my program has a bug ... pretend it never happened".  (If you wrote that in an answer to a interview question, I would show you the door.)

Comment: Yes. You cannot use floats, because you should not aim inbetween the RAM locations of 2 entries. And second, java programmers' RAM addressing in arrays can only take care of up to 2^31 slots, thus at the moment you're stuck with an `int`. You can also use byte and short, they usually get upcast without any problems.

Comment: @JayC667 - except in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Being_John_Malkovich :-)

Comment: I'm no Java expert, just taking an intro course. I found most of the array formula online. The problem was to find the maximum on these numbers being read from a text file. 
1.0
5.3
3.0
4.2
5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is replace

> for(double i = 0; i<=4; i++){

with

> for(int i = 0; i<=4; i++){

The **position** in the array can only be an integer value, the **value** at this array position is still double as you defined.

> double MaxArray[]

Further, I would replace <=4

> for(int i = 0; i **< MaxArray.length**; i++){

So you don't have to update the limit if you add/remove a value to the array.

Comment: Thank you! It works now but the System.out.println("The maximum number is: " + Max) does not display.

Comment: Nothing is printed to the console? Add a System.out.println in your catch to check if there is an exception.

Comment: @Madness7337 Did you notice that replacing 4 with the array length, it is now "<" and not anymore "<=" ?

Comment: No I did not, thank you for pointing that out! I'll make the adjustments after class and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Array indexes should not be double . Kindly check the difference with below code .

```
  import java.io.*;

public class Read {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Rayman7337\\IdeaProjects\\Exam2\\src\\Data.txt"));

            String Num_1 = br.readLine();
            String Num_2 = br.readLine();
            String Num_3 = br.readLine();
            String Num_4 = br.readLine();
            String Num_5 = br.readLine();

            double Convert_1 = Double.parseDouble(Num_1);
            double Convert_2 = Double.parseDouble(Num_2);
            double Convert_3 = Double.parseDouble(Num_3);
            double Convert_4 = Double.parseDouble(Num_4);
            double Convert_5 = Double.parseDouble(Num_5);

            double MaxArray[] = {Convert_1, Convert_2, Convert_3, Convert_4, Convert_5};

            double Max = MaxArray[0];

            for(int i = 0; i<=MaxArray.length; i++){
                if (MaxArray[i] > Max) Max = MaxArray[i];
            }
            System.out.println("The maximum number is: " + Max);

        }catch (Exception ex){
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove the greeting/signature on your post. See [Expected Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Array indices are integers so any type used as an array index must be safely cast to an int.  To solve your immediate problem, change the type of your for-loop index accordingly.

In addition, you can begin iteration on the second element of the array because you initialize `max` to the value of `maxArray[0]`.  The traditional form of the for-loop condition in this pattern is to use less-than-array-length.  Java naming convention is for variables to generally begin with lowercase letters.  With all that in mind...

```
double max = maxArray[0];
for (int i = 1 ; i < maxArray.length ; ++i) {
  if (maxArray[i] > max) {
    max = maxArray[i];
  }
}
```

Once you understand how this works, you could use a Stream to do it more succinctly.

```
double max = Arrays.stream(maxArray).max().getAsDouble();
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now but the System.out.println("The maximum number is: " + Max) does not display.

Comment: That sounds like a separate question.  Consider using a debugger on your code or at least putting some debug println statements to make sure your code is doing what you think its doing.